# Linux: Extract string from a line including delimiter character using sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I have a string like:

```
      xxxx:xx:x:1234::xxxx/128
```

I want to get characters until ::, the output should include "::" too.

If i try command:

```
          sed 's/::.*//'
```

The output is:

```
          xxxx:xx:x:1234   "::" characters are not included
```

How would i modify the sed command to include "::" characters in output.

Comment: You have to capture like this : `sed -n 's/^\(.*::\).*/\1/p' file`. Another : `sed 's/::.*/::/' file`

Comment: @sat Thanks very much

Comment: @sat please post it as answer

Comment: can also use `grep -o '.*::' file`